# How can i change value ListPreference from another Activity

Tags: java, android

I have Activity for ListPreference and i can change any values in it , but my question i want to change a value in ListPreference first time without the user enters to activity that there is ListPreference .
First time a user enters to an app i want to save default value depend on location the user.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(getString(R.string.settings_method_key),repear);
        editor.commit();
```